# Spyder don't launch

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have a problem with launch Spyder. When I try launch Spyder, it appear error: "Python has stopped working". I tried upgrade Anaconda, Python and reinstall Spyder, Python and Anaconda, but it didn't help.

When I try launch spyder via PowerShell, it is appear:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\USER> spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 763, in <lambda>
    lambda plugin_name, omit_conf: self.register_plugin(
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 217, in register_
plugin
    self.show_compatibility_message(message)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 1091, in __getatt
r__
    return super().__getattr__(attr)
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'show_compatibility_message'
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by upgrading the pyqt5 library with version 5.12.3:
`pip install pyqt5==5.12.3`

Comment: It doesn.t help me. I have upgraded pyqt5 library to 5.12.3 version.